# Redirect an odd format url

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm trying to get my page to redirect me to another page but the URL is in an odd format.
This is what it looks like:

url =http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?addresses={"records":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":1,"SingleLine":"380 New York St., Redlands, CA, 92373",}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":2,"SingleLine":"1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA, 90045",}}]}&sourceCountry=USA&token=&f=pjson.

I'm guessing I have to parse it somehow but I do not know how.

Comment: [`escape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) the url and set `window.location` to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode each URL query string parameter using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (al least the dynamic ones):

```
window.location.href = 'http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?addresses=' + encodeURIComponent('{"records":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":1,"SingleLine":"380 New York St., Redlands, CA, 92373",}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":2,"SingleLine":"1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA, 90045",}}]}') + '&sourceCountry=USA&token=&f=pjson';
```

further reading: [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)